# Is there a way to know when a tkinter ComboBox option is clicked?

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

In `tkinter` , `Buttons` have a parameter called `command` which causes some function to run whenever the button is clicked.

Is the same possible to do with the options of a `tkinter Combobox` ?

For example :

I have three options in the `tkinter Combobox` : `#1` , `#2` , `#3`

Now , As soon as `#1` is or clicked , I want to print something like `Options 1 Selected`.

Is it possible to do ?

P.S , As @Atlas435 pointed out about getting the selected value from the `tk.Combobox()` , I really dont want the value of the `Combobox()` , what I am asking is that whether there is way to make `Combobox` options work like `Buttons` which when clicked , causes some function to execute.

Comment: Yes and there are several questions on it. Search for combpbox and bind selected

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Getting the selected value from combobox in Tkinter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31264522/getting-the-selected-value-from-combobox-in-tkinter)

Comment: @Atlas435 , No there is a difference between getting the selected value and "executing a function as soon as an option is clicked" . I can get the value of the ComboBox anytime , thats not an issue. In other words , is there a way to make ComboBox options work like `tkinter Buttons` ?

Comment: Please read it, you will find the line `.bind('<<Selected>>')` or something like this

Comment: You can bind `<Button-1>` to a function.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take a look at this example, which does what you are asking for:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk

root = Tk()

def select(event): #the function to get triggered each time you choose something
    if c.get() == lst[0]: #if it is the first item
        print('Option 1 is selected')
    elif c.get() == lst[1]: #if it is the second item
        print('Option 2 is selected')
    else: #or if it is the third item
        print('Option 3 is selected')

lst = ['#1','#2','#3'] #creating option list

c = ttk.Combobox(root,values=lst,state='readonly') #creating a combobox
c.current(0) #setting first element as the item to be showed
c.pack(padx=10,pady=10) #putting on screen

c.bind('<<ComboboxSelected>>',select) #the event that your looking for 

root.mainloop()
```

Ive commented it to understand better, if any doubts or errors, do let me know